# Clojure Javascript Interop, multiple parameters

Tags: interop, clojurescript

I am a starter ClojureScript developer, making a front-end application, and so far I didn't have to use Javascript, because reagent is more than enough. But now I want to implement some Jquery for an easy scrollAnimation. Jayq is working, but I have problems with using the interop.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2000);
});
```

So far I could manage to write the first part, where I get the position of the div I want to scroll to.

```
(.-top (.offset ($ "#scrollto")))
```

But the second part is harder then I thought. I tried it like below and some similar solutions, which also didn't work.

```
#(.animate ($ "html" "body") (clj->js {"scrollTop" (.-top (.offset ($  "#scrollto")))
}) "2000")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(-> (js/$ "html, body")
    (.animate (clj->js {:scrollTop (-> (js/$ "#ide")
                                        (.offset)
                                        .-top)}) 
               2000))
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly what this code does, how it's different from the original code and why it solves the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is perfect, but I agree with JJJ-s comment, with some explaining next time I wouldn't even have to ask, I would know how and why it's done like that.

Comment: It looks like you were just missing accessing jQuery `$` properly. `js/$` is the correct syntax for accessing global variables in CLJS. As for the rest of the changes the answerer made, they are syntactic sugar and a pretty common pattern for accessing nested properties and methods of javascript objects in CLJS. The thread first operator '->' takes the first argument you pass it and passes it along as the first argument to subsequent function calls. So for example, the return result of (js/$ "html, body") gets passed as the first arg to .animate. Same as `(.animate (js/$ "html, body") ...`